# ASP.NET - MVC Sending and receiving model from controller to view and back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to send data fetched from database to the view, and then receive data back from the view to insert it into the database.
My problem is working with 2 instances of the same model.

Basically i want to show the user 10 random questions which he can answer with selection, and then I want to send back to the server id of the question and the answer he selected.

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var questions = db.Questions.Where(p => p.subject == "Subject").ToList();

        var sessionQuestions = questions.OrderBy(item => rand.Next()).Take(10);

        myModel model = new myModel
        {
            Questions = questions,
            randomSample = sessionQuestions,
            submitedAnswers = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        };
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(myModel m)
    {
        ViewBag["Sample"] = m.submitedAnswers;
        return RedirectToAction("Debug");
    }
```

View:

```
@model OnlineQuiz.Models.myModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    var i = 1;
    foreach (var item in Model.randomSample)
    {
        var possibleAnswers = @item.possibleAnswers.Split(',');

        <div class="question" style="display: block" id=@item.Id runat="server">
            <h4>@i. @item.question</h4>
            <ul runat="server">
                @foreach (var answer in possibleAnswers)
                {
                    <li class="btn btn-primary" style="display: block; margin-bottom:5px" runat="server">@answer</li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
        i++;
    }
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
 }
```

Comment: Your form doesn't have any form inputs.  Specifically where is the data that you are trying to post to the server?  (And what is `runat="server"`?)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `two instances of the same model`.  It looks like your first problem is your `BeginForm` doesn't know where to post to.

Comment: @David that's from webforms and not applicable to MVC

Comment: I haven't collected the data yet as I'm trying to get my head around working with the model i want to post back.



I'm planning to post a dictionary containing (id of question,selected answer) pairs

Comment: @smith: Well, if you haven't created a form for posting the data yet then that would explain why not data is being posted yet.  You would want to populate form elements (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc.) within your form, using `name` attributes which match your model (the `@Html...` helpers can help with that) to post values when submitting the form.  It sounds like you haven't encountered an actual problem yet and are just trying to understand the technology.  That's what tutorials are for.  You are encouraged to start with an introductory ASP.NET MVC tutorial.

Comment: I dont think you understood my problem.I'm showing the user 10 random questions and a list of answers, he then answers the questions by clicking on the wanted answer, after clicking submit, i want to post a dictionary containing a pair of (id,selectedAnswer) for every question the user answered, so i can calculate the score that the user made in that session in the controller

Comment: @smith: That's a description of what you want your application to do, but it's not a description of a specific problem you've encountered while building your application.  Given the code you currently have, what isn't working as expected?  As you stated, so far you haven't "collected the data" from the user.  So far you're just displaying information to the user.  Is something about that not working?  From what I can tell so far your question is simply, "How do I use ASP.NET MVC?"  Which of course is far too broad.  Can you be more specific about the problem?

Comment: @smith: As a side note... A `Dictionary<T, V>` likely isn't the best data model choice for this.  You may ultimately find it easier and more meaningful to build a simple "answer" model and use a `List<T>` of that model in your `myModel` class.

Comment: @David the code is completely working for what its mean to do, my problem was how do i send back data to the controller after i form the dictionary, as i said before

Comment: @smith: That would be the next step in whatever tutorial(s) you are following.  The `InputExtensions` helpers are available to bind things like text boxes, check boxes, drop down lists, etc. to your model properties: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions  For example, if your model has a `string` property, you might add a text box with: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty)`  For more complex models it of course gets a bit more complex.  You can also create your HTML manually.  As long as the `name` attribute matches the model, it'll bind when posted.

Comment: @smith let me know if you have any questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's fine to retrieve submitted answer with question id in array and later mapping to any model, I would suggest to make some changes on controller and views like as:

View:

```
@model OnlineQuiz.Models.myModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    var i = 1;
    foreach (var item in Model.randomSample)
    {
        var possibleAnswers = @item.possibleAnswers.Split(',');

        <div class="question" style="display: block" id="@item.Id">
            <h4>@i. @item.question</h4>
            <ul">
                @foreach (var answer in possibleAnswers)
                {
                    <li class="" style="display: block; margin-bottom:5px" >
                    <input type="checkbox" id="@item.Id _@answer" name="QuestionAnswer" value="@item.Id _@answer" /> @answer
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
        i++;
    }
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

and in Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string[] QuestionAnswer)
{
    // each QuestionAnswer contains only checked value in questionid_answer format
    // like :
    // 1_ansone
    // 1_ansone
    // 2_anstwo
    // 3_ansthree
    foreach(var item in QuestionAnswer){
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(item.Split('_')[0].Trim());
        string answer = item.Split('_')[1].Trim();
        // do save to database or map to model logic here
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Debug");
}
```

I hope this will help somehow.

Comment: Armit, thanks a lot for your effort, however, when I use this, the controller throws an error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object, the posted list of string is null probably, what may be the cause?

Comment: this may encounter inside **foreach** loop if there is no list value in string format like **1_ansone**.

Comment: please make sure checkbox element has name **name="QuestionAnswer" ** and value in same format **value="@item.Id _@answer"**

Comment: for reference, see view [link](https://github.com/amritpariyar/Learning-ASP.NET-MVC/blob/master/SOIT/Areas/HR/Views/Test/MultipleQuestion.cshtml) and controller [link](https://github.com/amritpariyar/Learning-ASP.NET-MVC/blob/master/SOIT/Areas/HR/Controllers/TestController.cs)

Answer (score 0):

What we need to achieve here is sending a view model that contains a structure for our questions and possible answers to a view. The user provides the answers and send the response back to the server.

In my design I have used JavaScript to handle the logic on the page and Ajax in order to submit the response back to the server.

I have created my example using .net core 3.1 and Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.4.2

In the JavaScript - each answer is mapped into an object :

```
    var answerObj = {
        id,
        value
    };
```

The `answerObj` contains the question id and the answer value.

The view model will have the following structure:

```
public class QuestionStructure
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string PossibleAnswear { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<QuestionStructure> Questions { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        QuestionStructure q1 = new QuestionStructure
        {
            Id = 1,
            Question = "How many days in a leap year?",
            PossibleAnswear = "2356,366,212,365"
        };
        QuestionStructure q2 = new QuestionStructure
        {
            Id = 2,
            Question = "What is the next number in the series 2, 3, 5, 7, 11...?",
            PossibleAnswear = "15,88,99,13"

        };
        QuestionStructure q3 = new QuestionStructure
        {
            Id = 3,
            Question = "How many wheel has a bike got?",
            PossibleAnswear = "5,3,4,2"
        };

        QuestionStructure q4 = new QuestionStructure
        {
            Id = 4,
            Question = "How many fingers have you got?",
            PossibleAnswear = "5,8,20,10"
        };

        List<QuestionStructure> items = new List<QuestionStructure>();
        items.Add(q1);
        items.Add(q2);
        items.Add(q3);
        items.Add(q4);

        this.Questions = items;
    }
}
```

Our controller will look like this and we send data to the view from the Index method:

```
    private ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.View(viewModel);
    }

    [Route("/homeController/returnedAnswers")]
    public List<ReturnedAnswers> Answers(string json)
    {
        List<ReturnedAnswers> returnedAnswers = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ReturnedAnswers>>(json);
        // here you can do all the logic to manipulate your result...
        // We just sent back to the ajax call the json data and we can check it in the console log
        return returnedAnswers;
    }
```

The cshtml page will receive a model of type ViewModel, please note that I have injected jQuery as a CDN in the HTML head:

```
@model ViewModel;

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var item in Model.Questions)
    {
        var question = @item.Question;
        var possibleAnswers = @item.PossibleAnswear.Split(',');

        <div class="question" style="display: block">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-5">
                    <label style="margin-right: 1rem">@question</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <select class="mySelect">
                        <option value="">Select a question</option>
                        @foreach (var answear in possibleAnswers)
                        {
                            <option value="@item.Id">@answear</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

The most important thing to note here is the for each loop where we set the drop down options. Each options will have the value of the question id and the text will be the possibleAnswer.

This design will allow us to later create our mapping object into JavaScript.

I have put the JavaScript into a different file - but it can be embedded directly into the page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var answers = [];

    //on change event for all our dropdown
    $(".mySelect").change(function () {

        var id = $(this).children(':selected').attr('value');
        var value = $(this).children(':selected').text();

        var answerObj = {
            id,
            value
        };

        // check if we are changing an already given answer.
        var alreadyIn = answers.find(item => item.id === id);

        //if so remove it from mapped array
        if (alreadyIn) {
            answers = answers.filter(item => item.id !== alreadyIn.id);
        }

        //map selected answer to our array of objects
        answerObj.id = id;
        answerObj.value = value;
        answers.push(answerObj);
    });

    // When the submit button is clicked send the request back to the server.
    // JSON.stringify(answers) will serialise our array of answers - into a Json format.
    $('#submit').on('click', function () {
        $.post({
            url: '/homeController/returnedAnswers',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { "json": JSON.stringify(answers) },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

What the js is doing here is quite simple.

Each time the user select a value from the dropdown we map the value and the text into our object:

```
var answerObj = {
    id,
    value
};
```

We then store it into an array.

```
    answerObj.id = id;
    answerObj.value = value;
    answers.push(answerObj);
```

That would be the answers mapping of questions ids and given answers.

Now we have the data structure - all we need to do is sending it back to the server.

```
$('#submit').on('click', function () {
    $.post({
        url: '/homeController/returnedAnswers',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { "json": JSON.stringify(answers) },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I have attached an event to the submit button which will trigger an Ajax post call to my route(url).

In our controller I have defined my routing to the following method:

```
[Route("/homeController/returnedAnswers")]
public List<ReturnedAnswers> Answers(string json)
{
    List<ReturnedAnswers> returnedAnswers = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ReturnedAnswers>>(json);
    // here you can do all the logic to manipulate your result...
    // We just sent back to the ajax call the json data and we can check it in the console log
    return returnedAnswers;
}
```

The method will receive a string parameter which will have the same structure as the following class:

```
public class ReturnedAnswers
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

As the result will be an array of objects - DeserializeObject will need to use a `List<ReturnedAnswers>`

For the purpose of the example I will be sending the data back to the client and display it into the console.log

Here you can see the result:
[image]

The array you see in the console(right hand side) is the response from the server after clicking submit.